# Attempt to read from field 'long android.graphics.Typeface.native_instance' on a null object reference -> App crashing in Motorolla phones

Tags: android, fonts, motorola

```
   Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'long android.graphics.Typeface.native_instance' on a null object reference in method 'void android.graphics.Typeface.setDefault(android.graphics.Typeface)'
       at android.graphics.Typeface.setDefault(Typeface.java:264)
       at android.graphics.Typeface.init(Typeface.java:1508)
       at android.graphics.Typeface.updateThemeFont(Typeface.java:1579)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6944)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication()
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2219)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:238)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:357)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8088)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:957)
```

App is working fine on all other Android Devices and font family SourceSansPro_Regular working fine too but
app is crashing giving attached crash logs in Motorolla devices.
SourceSansPro_Regular.ttf is put inside src -> main -> assets -> SourceSansPro_Regular.ttf